# Sum items in master detail using LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-5

I am trying to get the total of each invoice in a table from the sum of the invoice items.

My invoice data model is

```
public class Invoice
{
    [Key]
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool Paid { get; set; }
    public bool Printed { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer customer { get; set; }

}
```

and my invoiceitem data model is

```
public class InvoiceItem
{
    [Key]
    public int InvoiceItemId { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string PartNo { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int TaxId { get; set; }
    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

To populate the grid I have

```
            response.Records.Add(new JqGridRecord(Convert.ToString(x.Invoice.InvoiceId), new InvoiceEditViewModel()
            {
                Id = x.Invoice.InvoiceId,
                CustomerName = x.Customer.Name,
                Total =  x.Invoice.InvoiceItems.Where(p => p.InvoiceId == x.Invoice.InvoiceId).Sum(d => d.Price * d.Quantity ),
                InvType = x.Invoice.Type,
                Notes = x.Invoice.Notes,
                Date = x.Invoice.Date.ToShortDateString(),
                Number = x.Invoice.Number,
                Printed = x.Invoice.Printed,

            }));

        }
```

However, this throws an error when calculating the total

"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first"

I would appreciate how to resolve this one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that what I needed was to add

MultipleActiveResultSets=true;

In my connection string.